# How can we render graphviz diagrams in drupal pages?

Tags: 7

I'd like to be able to allow users to insert [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) images in Drupal comments and Wiki pages.

What's involved it doing this?

The benefit is that users could enter something like the following snippet to see a graph.

```
[code lang=graphviz]
  digraph G {
    a  [label="Hello", shape="square", URL="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/graphviz"]
    F1 -> a[label=".63"]
  }
[/code]
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [Graphviz Filter](http://drupal.org/project/graphviz_filter) module, which provides an input filter that will convert Graphviz DOT syntax to the required diagrams. You can find more information in the Drupal [documentation on graphing modules](http://drupal.org/node/1389294).